# Model field to automatically store total club members

Tags: python, django, orm

I am building an app for a charity club that has many different users each belonging to a single club. I want to automatically increment the 'total_members' field of the class 'Club_Chapter' each time a user registers their account for a particular school (hence the User foreign key 'chapter').

models.py

```
class Club_Chapter(models.Model):
    club_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    total_members = models.IntegerField(null = False, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

# User Model 
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Club_Chapter',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ranking = models.CharField(default='member', max_length=20)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True)
    chapter =  models.ForeignKey('Club_Chapter',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    password2 = None

    # below is my failed attempt to solve this problem
    Club_Chapter.objects.update(total_members=F('total_members') + 1)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 
        'chapter','email', 'password1',)
```

I know this seams like a trivial problem but I have been searching everywhere with no luck. Any input will be greatly appreciated for the solution to this problem will help greatly with other aspects of this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what it's important to have an auto-incrementing `total_members` fields. Django has super powerful querying capabilities. For instance, this would work perfectly:

```
total_members = User.objects.filter(chapter__school_name="My Cool School").count()
```

Notice I used the double underscore after chapter to reference a particular field in the foreign key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Josh sorry for the beginner question but, where would I put this query forms.py, views.py?

Comment: @ColinSather No worries. This goes in the views.py file.